# react rendering proplem with map

Tags: components, rendering

```js
let pendingdatafilterd = data.map((itm, i) => {

    const [status, setStatus] = useState(itm.status);
    if (status == 'pending') {
      return (
        <div key={i} >
        <div>{itm.id}</div>
        <div>{status}</div>
        <button onClick={() => { setStatus('finished'); itm.status = 'finished'; setfinishedData(finishedData => [...finishedData, itm]);  }} >finish</button>
      </div>
      )
    }

    console.log('rendered')
})
```

This is part of my code and the problem is that the component render number is rising every time I click the button.

Comment: i solved it by adding "return" after if condition had end